# Failure only on Android 6 WebView - jQuery 1.9.1 uncaught RangeError maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, webview, android-6.0-marshmallow

A web application is failing with "Uncaught RangeError Maximum call stack size exceeded" error in jQuery-1.9.1's extend() function, **only on Android 6**.

It works fine on all other platforms like Desktop Chrome, Chrome on Android 6, iOS Safari etc.

Here's the stacktrace -

```
jquery-1.9.1.min.js:1 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceededia.extend.ia.fn.extend @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:1ia.extend.ia.fn.extend @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:1ia.extend.ia.fn.extend @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:1ia.extend.ia.fn.extend @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:1ia.extend.ia.fn.extend @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:1ia.extend.ia.fn.extend @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:1ia.extend.ia.fn.extend @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:1ia.extend.ia.fn.extend @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:1ia.extend.ia.fn.extend @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:1ia.extend.ia.fn.extend @ jquery-1.9.1.min.js:1
```

When debugged on Android 6 WebView, I found that, jquery's [extend() function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/#jQuery-extend-deep-target-object1-objectN) is called for deep cloning, by passing parameter "deep" as true. When this call is made the function goes into the recursion and doesn't come out, and in turn fails due to RangeError.

However, this exactly same call works perfectly fine on every other platform. Even I checked the objects being passed to extend() function on Chrome browser or Android 6's native browser (where it works fine) and Android 6's WebView, and both objects are exactly the same with deep passed as true to the extend() function.

Call stack from Android 6's WebView -

[image: Call stack from Android 6's WebView]

And here’s the stack when run in native Android 6 browser –
Here $.extend() doesn’t go in the recursion.

[image: stack when run in native Android 6 browser]

Any ideas how this issue can be resolved without updating jQuery?

Comment: One more update - the same call that goes into recursion works fine if debugged manually via Chrome Dev Tools.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of experiments, I found the root cause of the issue –

The $.extend() method of jQuery uses $.isPlainObject() method to check if the object is plain object or not. One of the checks in this method checks, if the object has constructor and constructor, has a prototype, and if it does, then it isn’t a plain object. And it uses hasOwnProperty() method which is native JavaScript function.

But, in the case of Android 6’s WebView, hasOwnProperty() returned wrong Boolean value i.e. false even when it had constructor.prototype.

Because of this behavior on Android 6’s WebView, the $.extend() function continues with cloning of the object which is not plain object. And in my case, this exact scenario occurred when the object was not plain object, and it had a reference to the self which causes the cycle, and code goes into infinite recursion.

However, when the same code is put into a debugger, and when a significant amount of time is passed since the time of the non-plain object instance creation, the hasOwnProperty() function returns the correct value, which was causing it to behave correctly while debugging but it was failing when not debugging.

So for working around this issue, I overrode the extend function in my app when it loads, with the additional check to avoid this situation.